# Django Ajax Likes Work Incorrectly: Problem With jQuery

Tags: python, jquery, json, ajax, django

I have a **Like** feature, which works fine for the **"Detailed Product"**. However, I want to add this feature on the main page, where multiple products are shown. Not sure, how to correctly do that.

**urls.py**:

```
url(r'^like$', views.like_product, name='like_product')
```

script in the **base.html**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(event){
        $(document).on('click', '#like', function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            var pk = $(this).attr('value');
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '{% url 'like_product' %}',
                data: {'id': pk, 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'},
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(response){
                    $('#like-section').html(response['form'])
                    console.log($('#like-section').html(response['form']));
                },
                error: function(rs, e){
                    console.log(rs.responseText);
                },
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

**likes.html**:

```
<form action="{% url 'like_product' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% if is_liked %}
        <button type="submit" id="like" name="product_id" value="{{ product.id }}" class="btn btn-danger">Dislike</button>
    {% else %}
        <button type="submit" id="like" name="product_id" value="{{ product.id }}" class="btn btn-primary">Like</button>
    {% endif %}
</form>
```

**views.py**:

```
def home(request):
    products = Product.objects.all().order_by('-pub_date')
    f = ProductFilter(request.GET, queryset=products)
    context = {
        'filter': f,
    }
    return render(request, 'product/home.html', context).


def detail(request, product_id):
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, product_id=product_id)
    is_liked = False
    if product.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
        is_liked = True
    context = {
        'product': product,
        'is_liked': is_liked,
        'total_likes': product.total_likes()
    }
    return render(request, 'product/detail.html', context)


def like_product(request):
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=request.POST.get('id'))
    is_liked = False
    if product.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
        product.likes.remove(request.user)
        is_liked = False
    else:
        product.likes.add(request.user)
        is_liked = True
    context = {
        'product': product,
        'is_liked': is_liked,
        'total_likes': product.total_likes()
    }
    if request.is_ajax():
        html = render_to_string('product/likes.html', context, request=request)
        return JsonResponse({'form': html})
```

Likes/Dislikes are being recorded correctly if clicked from the main page, however they are not correctly displayed (actual amount of likes and Dislike button can only be seen on the "Detailed Product" page). I suspect this is because I have `id="like"` in the **likes.html** for both buttons. I suspect the `jQuery` script needs to be changed as well. Not sure how to do that. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are getting ID from URL to details page. It really depends how you are generating the list of products on the page but if you are using loop in templates then just add like button under each product and then use it's id to set up like form.

Comment: The problem might be in the **likes.html** form. I have `id="like"` for both Like and Dislike buttons. Which is fine for the "Detailed Product" page, as there is only one button, either Dislike or Like. But this is not going to work for the main page, where both buttons might be shown. Not quite sure how to fix that.